# Nested transactions are not allowed

Tags: android, realm

How is it possible to delete multiple objects from realm?

```
realm.beginTransaction
realm.executeTransaction(realm -> {
        for(String id : listOfIds) {

         realm.where(StorageClass.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst().removeFromRealm();
        }
      }
  );
realm.commitTransaction();
```

If i do the above and try to delete all ids from an existing list of ids, it gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nested transactions are not allowed. Use commitTransaction() after each beginTransaction().
    at io.realm.internal.ImplicitTransaction.promoteToWrite(ImplicitTransaction.java:39)
    at io.realm.Realm.beginTransaction(Realm.java:1435)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just remove realm.beginTransaction() and realm.commitTransaction() because execute transaction internally calls begin and commit transaction.